# How Can I have different amount of view each row in ListView?

Tags: android, listview

I want to have TextViews  each row in ListView.The amount of ListView depends on the data I use.
One of the solution to this is create layout files which contain different size of ListViews.
But in this way, I have to make hundreds of layout files.Is there any better way?

Comment: **Amount of listView** ??  what do you mean by that?? and you want `TextView` in each row or `ListView` ?? because you are talking to create lay out files with `listView`. Please be precise..!!

Comment: @jankigadhiya I mean I use ListView that contains TextView.And each row of the listView ,the amount of TextView is different.So its like one row may have 3 textview and another row may have 2.But the amount of the textview depends on the data.So I have to make hundreds of layout files.

Comment: No don't make hundred files.. Just tell me how you are getting to know the number of TextView in Each row..?? Share some code(Activity+Adapter) in question i Will try to suggest some logic If i can..!!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to make many layout files, another alternative is to insert those `TextView`s programmatically into the rows in `getView()` method on your `Adapter`.